# Show Google picture after log in using .Net Core v3 with razor pages

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, .net-core-3.0

I'm in the process of building a new application using Blazor and .NET Core v3.

As authentication, I want to use our Google G Suite.

I managed to log in, but I struggle to get to profile picture to show in my header.

This is my Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
            {
                IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection =
                    Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");

                options.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];

                options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo";
                options.ClaimActions.Clear();
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "given_name");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Surname, "family_name");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:profile", "link");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("image", "picture");

                options.Events = new OAuthEvents
                {
                    OnCreatingTicket = context =>
                    {                            
                        var myProfile = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(context.User.ToString());

                        if (myProfile.ContainsKey("picture"))
                        {
                            var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;
                            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("picture", myProfile["picture"].ToString()));
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
    }
```

And this is my _LoginPartial.cshtml

```
    @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <form class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Page("/", new { area = "" })" method="post">
                <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
            </form>
        </li>
        @foreach (var claim in User.Claims)
        {
            <span>@claim.Type : @claim.Value</span>
        }
    }
```

I assumed `options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey` would fill my `User.Claims`. But in my `foreach` only the 4 basic claims exist.

I know `myProfile["picture"]` hold the url to the profile picture. But I can't get it in my Login page.

I already tried:

```
var info = await SignInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
if (info != null)
{
    var avatar = info.Principal.FindFirst("picture");
}
```

**Update**:
`myProfile` contains:

```
[0]: {[id, ValueKind = String : "1095252652..."]}
[1]: {[email, ValueKind = String : "paul..."]}
[2]: {[verified_email, ValueKind = True : "True"]}
[3]: {[name, ValueKind = String : "Paul.."]}
[4]: {[given_name, ValueKind = String : "Paul"]}
[5]: {[family_name, ValueKind = String : ".."]}
[6]: {[picture, ValueKind = String : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/A..."]}
[7]: {[locale, ValueKind = String : "nl"]}
[8]: {[hd, ValueKind = String : "..."]}
```

Comment: you map `image` to `picture` but you test for a `picture` in the `OnCreatingTicket`. Did you try to test for `image` ? (`if (myProfile.ContainsKey("image"))`)

Comment: Thanks @aguafrommars. I've added the output of my myProfile dictionary. As you can see "picture" holds the correct value. And when I look at `identity.Claims` I have 6 claims including first name and picture. But I'm not sure how to read these claims in my login page.

Comment: IMO the issue is your `OnCreatingTicket`delegate, you should add claims to the `context.Identity`

Comment: Do you mean I should add it like `context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("picture", myProfile["picture"].ToString()));` But my User object in the Login page still has no extra claims.

Comment: Yes, In a project it's how I setup a GitHub authentication with OAuth provider

Comment: @aguafrommars Could you show me how you add the photo in the razor page. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: `<img src="@url />` but it's not the issue if you don't have the `picture` claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article shows code that works:
[Google Authentication in Server Side Blazor](http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4356/Google-Authentication-in-Server-Side-Blazor.aspx)

This change to the **startup.cs** may be what you need:

```
        services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["Google:ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Google:ClientSecret"];
            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:profile", "link");
            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:image", "picture");
        });
```

You can display the image with a .razor control like this:

```
@using System.Security.Claims
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor
@inject HttpClient Http
@if (User.Identity.Name != null)
{
    <img src="@Avatar" />
    <b>You are logged in as: @GivenName @Surname</b>
    <a class="ml-md-auto btn btn-primary"
       href="/Logout"
       target="_top">Logout</a>
}
else
{
    <a class="ml-md-auto btn btn-primary"
       href="/Login"
       target="_top">Login</a>
}
@code {
    private ClaimsPrincipal User;
    private string GivenName;
    private string Surname;
    private string Avatar;
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        try
        {
            // Set the user to determine if they are logged in
            User = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
            // Try to get the GivenName
            var givenName =
                _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User
                .FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName);
            if (givenName != null)
            {
                GivenName = givenName.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                GivenName = User.Identity.Name;
            }
            // Try to get the Surname
            var surname =
                _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User
                .FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Surname);
            if (surname != null)
            {
                Surname = surname.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                Surname = "";
            }
            // Try to get Avatar
            var avatar =
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User
            .FindFirst("urn:google:image");
            if (avatar != null)
            {
                Avatar = avatar.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                Avatar = "";
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, your answer is exactly what I was looking for. Hopefully, Google will rank it higher now because I wished I had found your site weeks earlier.